grub error "symbol 'grub_disk_native_sectors' not found" after trying to update 22.04 to 24.04
This is the second time trying to upgrade Ubuntu and ending up with a total mess.  Message telling me I have 22.04 LTS and 24.04 LTS is available.  Clicked UPGRADE.  After what seemed to be a successful upgrade, I hit reboot.  Now all I get is: error: symbol 'grub-disk_native_sectors' not found.  Entering rescue mode... grub rescue>
All attempts to find a solution to this have failed.  I even reinstalled 24.04.1 LTS ALONG SIDE the 24.04.1 LTS that is supposedly already on the boot disk.  WTF!!!!!
I love Linux but this is EXTREMELY frustrating and I DO NOT want to lose any data from my 3 hard drives.
